# PageX and PageY with Javascript drag event

Tags: javascript, drag, crop

I have an browser app that puts a set of crop marks over an image. The crop marks are 100px x 100px and are black forming a corner in the upper right and lower left. The crop marks start at the upper right and lower left border of the image and then can be independently dragged (trying this on an iPad in Mobile Safari). The drag event will tell me via PageX and PageY where the element is. I'm noticing two things though I don't understand.

For starters once I touch a crop mark it jumps to about 100px below my finger so I am moving it from above.

Secondly, when I get the drag event and particularly the final one before my finger lifts, I'm not sure where it is calculating PageX and PageY at. I need to determine where the corners of these two crop marks are so I can determine the location and dimensions of the cropped area. I don't know if it is calculating a location based on where my finger is and if I can determine where the corners are.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Gestures</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/main.css">

        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">

        <script type="text/javascript" src="resources/js/jquery-1.6.2.js"></script> 
        <script type="text/javascript" src="resources/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="resources/js/jquery.event.drag.min.js"></script>        
        <!--script src="resources/js/prototype.js" type="text/javascript"></script-->    
        <script type="text/javascript">
        var ll_curX = 50;
        var ll_curY = 285;
        var ur_curX = 350;
        var ur_curY = 60;

        $(function () 
        {
            $('#ur_corner').bind('drag', function (event) 
            {
                curX = event.pageX;
                curY = event.pageY;
                offsetX = curX - ur_curX;
                offsetY = curY - ur_curY;
                document.all.log.innerHTML += "...Drag curX = " + curX + ", curY = " + curY + ", offX =  "  + offsetX + ", offY = " + offsetY + "...</br>";                                     
                var $this = $(this);
                $(this).css({
                    left: (event.pageX-100) + 'px',
                    top: (event.pageY) + 'px'
                });
                //ur_curX = event.pageX;
                //ur_curY = event.pageY;
                ur_curX = curX + offsetX;
                ur_curY = curY + offsetY;

                //document.all.log.innerHTML += "...Drag left = " + event.pageX + ", top = " + event.pageY + "...</br>";
            });
        });     

        $(function () 
        {
            $('#ll_corner').bind('drag', function (event) 
            {
                curX = event.pageX;
                curY = event.pageY;
                offsetX = curX - ll_curX;
                offsetY = curY - ll_curY;

                var $this = $(this);
                $(this).css({
                    left: (event.pageX) + 'px',
                    top: (event.pageY-100) + 'px'
                });
                //ll_curX = event.pageX;
                //ll_curY = event.pageY;
                ll_curX = curX + offsetX;
                ll_curY = curY + offsetY;

                //document.all.log.innerHTML += "...Drag left = " + event.pageX + ", top = " + event.pageY + "...</br>";
            });
        });                 

        $(function ()
        {
            $('#cropButton').bind('click', function(event)
            {
                crop_id = "crop";
                img_id = "page";
                x = ll_curX;
                y = ur_curY;
                width = ur_curX - 50; // - ll_curX;
                height = ll_curY - ur_curY;
                document.all.log.innerHTML += "...Crop ll_curyY = " + ll_curY + ", ur_curY = " + ur_curY + "...</br>";
                document.all.log.innerHTML += "...Crop x = " + x + ", y = " + y + ", width = " + width + ", height = " + height + "...</br>";
                $('#crop').html('<img id="crop_img" src="resources/images/cervelor3.jpg" />');
                $('#crop').css({
                    position: 'relative',
                    overflow: 'hidden' 
                });

                //var scale_x = $('#crop').getWidth() / width;
                //var scale_y = $('#crop').getHeight() / height;                    
                document.all.log.innerHTML += "...Crop ll_curyY = " + ll_curY + ", ur_curY = " + ur_curY + "...</br>";

                $('#crop_img').css({
                    position: 'absolute',
                    display: 'block',
                    left: x + 'px', //left: (-x * scale_x) + 'px',
                    top: y + 'px', //top: (-y * scale_y) + 'px',
                    width: width + 'px', //$('#page').getWidth() * scale_x) + 'px',
                    height: height + 'px' //($('#page').getHeight() * scale_y) + 'px'
                });

            /*              
                $(crop_id).update('<img id="' + crop_id + '_img" src="' +
                    $(img_id).getAttribute('src') + '" style="display:none" />');

                var scale_x = $(crop_id).getWidth() / width;
                var scale_y = $(crop_id).getHeight() / height;

                $(crop_id).setStyle({
                    position: 'relative',
                    overflow: 'hidden' 
                });

                $(crop_id + '_img').setStyle({
                    position: 'absolute',
                    display: 'block',
                    left: x + 'px', //left: (-x * scale_x) + 'px',
                    top: y + 'px', //top: (-y * scale_y) + 'px',
                    //width: width + 'px', //($(img_id).getWidth() * scale_x) + 'px',
                    height: height + 'px' //($(img_id).getHeight() * scale_y) + 'px'
                });
                //document.all.log.innerHTML += "...Crop left = " + x + ", top = " + y + ", scale_x = " + scale_x + ", scale_y = " + scale_y + "...</br>";
                document.all.log.innerHTML += "...Crop height = " + height + ", width = " + width + "...</br>";
            */
            });
        }); 

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container" style="width:800px; height:40px;">              
        <div id="header" style="background-color:#FFA500;">
            <h1 style="margin-bottom:0;">Print Preview</h1>
        </div>
        <div id="preview" style="background-color:#FFD700;height:600px;width:400px;float:left;">
            <div id="paper">
                <!--div id="clipping" style="width:300px; height:225px"-->
                    <img id="page" src="resources/images/cervelor3.jpg" height="225px" width="300px">
                    <div id="clip"> 
                        <img id="ll_corner" src="resources/images/lowerleftcorner.png" height="100px" width="100px">                                                
                        <img id="ur_corner" src="resources/images/upperrightcorner.png" height="100px" width="100px">   
                    </div>                                              
                <!--/div-->                     
            </div>
            <div id = "buttonDiv">
                <!-- Pass crop() the original image id, the id of the div to receive the crop, the left and top position of the
                     area to crop, then the width, and height of the crop -->
                <button id="cropButton" type="button">Crop</button>
            </div>
            <div id="crop" style="width:300px; height:225px;">
                <img src="resources/images/cervelor3.jpg" style="height:225px; width:300px;">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="content" style="background-color:#EEEEEE;height:600px;width:400px;float:left;">
            <h2>Print Settings</h2>
            </br>
            <label class=copies>Copies</label>
            <textarea class="box" cols="1" rows="1">1</textarea>
            </br></br></br>
            <label class=duplex>2-Sided</label>
            <textarea class="box" cols="1" rows="1">Off</textarea>                              
            </br></br></br>
            <label class=contrast>Contrast</label>
            <input class=slider type="range"  min="0" max="100" value="50" step="5"/>
            <div id="log">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="footer" style="background-color:#FFA500;clear:both;text-align:center;">Copyright © 2012 www.hp.com</div>
    </div>      
    <!-- div id="trace"></div> -->          
    <!-- div id="gesture" style="background:red;width:300px;height:300px;z-index:5000;position:absolute"><div> -->          
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I believe I know the issue you're referencing with the jump, however I can't be sure if there isn't any code to debug.

Comment: I am trying to add my code but I can't figure out what it wants in terms of indenting to get my code to appear. It keeps saying it is not formatted correctly.